# Separate frontend and backend for a multilingual WordPress/Joomla website

Tags: wordpress, joomla, frontend, backend, subdomain

I am desperately searching for a way to do that. I don't know even if it's possible or not. Here is what I want-

I want to build a multilingual WordPress or joomla blog website (for example- website.com) where the Administrator link will be on a subdomain or on a different domain (for example- admin.website.com). And the authors will still use a different dashboard to submit articles. It could be another subdomain or a subdirectory like link (for example- account.website.com or website.com/user).

I have tried installing WordPress in subdomain and changing site url to main domain but it didn't work.
And for joomla, I couldn't find any way to change the site url.

How do I achieve that?
Is it possible?